# How to create a file in edit mode and have a path to it in build? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code can create files and they will contain various data about spawners, players, spaces, etc. I made it so that players can also create these files and the code can access them (via Application.persistentDataPath). There is another problem here: if I create such a file in the editing mode, the Application.persistentDataPath is completely different on Windows, so this data will not be included in the build.

To summarise: what path should I choose in order to create several files there during the development stage and have access to it in build? (maybe somehow get access to the Resources folder?)

Comment: put it into `Application.streamingAssets` (= `Assets/StreamingAsset` in the editor) and then copy them out into `Application.persistentDataPath` on first app start

Comment: For android, I have to use AssetBundle, but its LoadAsset() method returns a UnityEngine.Object. Instead, my file is an array of bytes. Also, I would not really want to depend on the server during the development phase, it takes time to debug

Comment: as said just create them in `StreamingAssets` and within the editor use always `Application.streamingAssets` ... then in a build for all files check if they are contained in `Application.persistentDataPath` -> if not copy from `Application.streamingAssets` into `Application.persistentDataPath` -> from now one use `Application.persistentDataPath`

Comment: @derHugo "On Android and WebGL platforms, it’s not possible to access the streaming asset files directly via file system APIs and streamingAssets path because these platforms return a URL. Use the UnityWebRequest class to access the content instead." - Unity docs. I can't just take the `StreamingAssets` folder in the build and access it. Everything works perfectly on the computer, but when I make a build on my android phone, the data is not received

Comment: emphasis her lies on **directly** .. you can still access them via `UnityWebRequest` as mentioned there as well